# MassTransit HealthCheck

Tags: c#, .net, masstransit, health-check

is it possible to disable health checks on a certain queue. We get exceptions, when the queue is used exclusively.

````
MassTransit.RabbitMqConnectionException: ReceiveTransport faulted: ...
 ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=403, text='ACCESS_REFUSED - queue 'my-test-queue' in vhost '...' in exclusive use', classId=60, methodId=20```
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is not possible.